# Notification on change Phone Number

Tags: architecture, phone-number, telecommunication

Assume a phone number 111-111-1111 belonged to customer A, who now wants to give up this number (111-111-1111). Do carriers or FCC publish events or notify users or other carriers that this number is no longer used and is available for customers to use?

If yes then how, is there a way or SDK to get notified whenever a phone number becomes available?

Answer (score 0):

Each region or country may have it's own scheme but assuming you are asking about US numbers then the numbers are managed by the NANPA, the North American Numbering Plan Administrator.

This is overseen by the FCC and operated by companies who bid to run it - currently it is SOMOS.

US numbers consists of three parts (NPA-NXX-NNNN)

- NPA - is the Number Plan Area code (e.g 212 is one of the New York City, Manhattan ones)
- NXX - is the exchange code
- NNNN - is the 'line' number

The NANPA assign CIC codes and publish a process to apply for them. Individual service providers then assign individual 'line' numbers.

AFAIK, there is no US wide process or API to list and apply for unused or free numbers at this time.